Compositions of $n$ into $k$ parts such that the $i$th part is $i$ or $i+1$
In my homework, I have encountered such a question: Determine the number of compositions of $n$ into $k$ parts such that the $i$th part is $i$ or $i+1$.
I have also been given the following procedure for counting compositions:

Write the set $S$ of sequences to be counted.
Write $S_i$, the set of possible values of $x_i$, and observe $S_1 \times S_2 \times \ldots \times S_k$.
Write $\Phi_{S_i}(x)$ in closed form.
Write $\Phi_S(x)=\prod_{i=1}^k \Phi_{S_i}(x)$ using the product lemma.
Using the binomial theorem, expand $\Phi_S(x)$ as a sum.
Determine $\left[x^n\right] \Phi_S(x)$ by carefully choosing the summation variable in (5).
If necessary, write $\left[x^n\right] \Phi_S(x)$ in terms of "positive" binomial coefficients.

So far I have figured out that:

$S$ is the set of sequences $(x_1,x_2,...,x_k)$ where $x_i$ is either $i$ or $i + 1$, and
$S_i=\{i,i+1\}$ since $S_i$ is the set of possible values that $x_i$ can take.

From there, I'm not quite sure where to go. Is $\Phi_{S_i}(x)=x^i+x^{i+1}$? That's all I can think of, but it feels like something is off. I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Perhaps try brute-forcing some small values of $n$ and see if a pattern emerges.

It is much simpler than that.  Given $k$, what is the minimum value that $n$ can have for there to be one?  What is the maximum value?  As long as $n$ is in this range, how many of the parts are $i+1$?  To get the number of compositions you just need to count the number of ways to distribute the $+1$s.
